# only the first record in table is affected by javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have script that can automatically calculate age depending on the birthdate. But it only works on the first row in the table.

HTML

```
<div class="input-group input-group-sm">
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1" style="width:92% ">Date of Birth:</span>
         <input type="date" class="form-control" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" style="width:153.8%;" id="birthdateEdit" name="birthdateEdit" value="<?php echo $row['birthdate']; ?>" required="">
    </div>

<div class="input-group input-group-sm">
   <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1" style="width:84% ">Age:</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" style="width:140%;" placeholder="Enter age" id="ageEdit" name="ageEdit" value="<?php echo $row['age']; ?>" >
  </div>
```

Script that auto calculate age.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#birthdateEdit").change(function(){
           var value = $("#birthdateEdit").val();
            var dob = new Date(value);
            var today = new Date();
            var age = Math.floor((today-dob) / (365.25 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            if(isNaN(age)) { 
             age=0;
            }
            else{
              age=age;
            }
            $('#ageEdit').val(age);
        });
    });
```

Comment: the onchange is applied to only one control here.. use it for a class instead of an id.

Comment: where `#birthdateEdit` I can't show in code??

Comment: I already edited the question.

Comment: Make `today = Date.now()`.

Comment: id's must be unique in HTML - this is not your issue, but you do have 2 x `id="sizing-addon1"`

Comment: One `id` with that value per page.

Comment: its aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" @JaromandaX

Comment: You must've posted the wrong html then. I see 2 spans with that id

Comment: oh I see @JaromandaX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just try to update your script with `.each()` function and changed id with classes. I used simple HTML table to go through, check below snippet for reference.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dob").each(function() {
    var value = $(this).text();
    var dob = new Date(value);
    var today = new Date();
    var age = Math.floor((today - dob) / (365.25 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    if (isNaN(age)) {
      age = 0;
    } else {
      age = age;
    }
    $(this).next('.age').text(age);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>DOB</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="dob">10/10/1991</td>
      <td class="age"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="dob">2/21/1992</td>
      <td class="age"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="dob">12/27/1989</td>
      <td class="age"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="dob">11/14/1981</td>
      <td class="age"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Snippet in javascript is written only for a selector $("#birthdateEdit") , So when its applied only for one line item.

When you write a snippet in order to to get all the id or class which has the birthdate (jQuery('#xx').each(function(ind,obj){//do stuff;});) pass through your calculating age logic and update the same in the following "ageEdit" which is before the "#birthdateEdit" should work.

For multiple Selections you can use the below snippet also

jQuery("div[id=elementid]") - All the div elements which contains the respective id

$(document).ready(function() {
                    $('div input[name=birthdateEdit]').each(function() {
                        var value = $(this).attr('value');
                        var dob = new Date(value);
                        var today = new Date();
                        var age = Math.floor((today - dob) / (365.25 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
                        age = (isNaN(age)) ? 0 : age;
                        // Find the parent of the current and next sibling will land you in the div where you should update the age exist
                    });

```
<h3>Age Calculator</h3>
<div class="input-group input-group-sm">
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1" style="width:92% ">Date of Birth:</span>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" style="width:153.8%;" id="birthdateEdit" name="birthdateEdit" value="1988-02-25" required="">
</div>

<div class="input-group input-group-sm">
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1" style="width:84% ">Age:</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" style="width:140%;" placeholder="Enter age" id="ageEdit" name="ageEdit" value="">
</div>

<br>

<div class="input-group input-group-sm">
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1" style="width:92% ">Date of Birth:</span>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" style="width:153.8%;" id="birthdateEdit" name="birthdateEdit" value="1988-06-25" required="">
</div>

<div class="input-group input-group-sm">
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1" style="width:84% ">Age:</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" style="width:140%;" placeholder="Enter age" id="ageEdit" name="ageEdit" value="">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks I get the idea, but can you pls tell me how to do it exactly?